# Variable Concate on shell_exec command

Tags: java, php, shell-exec

I have to execute a jar file from PHP and I have to pass an argument.

I have this function

```
function sensesOfSentence($sentence){
    $command = sprintf('"C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\java" -jar lesk.jar %s', $sentence);
    return json_decode(shell_exec($command));
}
```

works in this way

```
$s = 'the cat and the roof'
echo sensesOfSentence($s);
```

**Output:**

```
The command is: "C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\java" -jar lesk.jar the cat and the roof

Array ( [0] => any of several large cats typically able to roar and living in the wild [1] => a protective covering that covers or forms the top of a building )
```

but, not in that way

```
$owlParsedJson = file_get_contents('owls-dump.php');
$owlParsed = json_decode($owlParsedJson);
echo sensesOfSentence(owlParsed->sentence);
```

**Output:**

```
The command is: "C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\java" -jar lesk.jar the cat and the roof

Array ()
```

When I print the variable command I can see the correct sentence, but doenst work.

Comment: i read it twice, me and the owls are totally confused

Comment: i believe you dont want file_get_contents() you should use include\require and then you still need to call the function

Comment: @Dagon I have to use file_get_contents() because owls-dump.php returns a json object.

Comment: @Dagon the most important is that owlParsed->sentence is a string ("the cat and the roof" per example)